# Test sort api in mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I test my nodejs app using mongodb and my api has sort feature. So I test the sort feature like this

```
            const result = await request
                .get('/api/items')
                .query({field, sort})
                .set('Authorization', token)

            // Expect
            expect(result.status).toEqual(httpStatus.OK)

            const {data} = result.body
            expect(data.length).toEqual(items.length)

            const sortedItems = _.orderBy(items, [field], [sort])


            data.forEach((item, index: number) => {
                expect(item).toEqual(sortedItems[index])
            })
```

Forexample, I sort the field 'name' and sort direction 'asc'. I could fail if there are 2 items having the same name because the sort function in mongoose and lodash is a little bit different. And if the sorted field has the same value, the order maybe different.

How to test sort feature in nodejs using mongoose? Thanks